# I have a problem with a function to pick random and count in order to create dependencies

Tags: python

I first tried to write a program which creates plans for my roommates when we do cleaning. So we got a list of the roommates a, b, c, d. This list is defined, then the program should choose as many random objects from the list as you say in the input part for the code, most times I use "12". In order to prevent that the same name is chosen like 3 times in a row, the code should count how often one element appears in the list and remove one item from the list when it appears more than 1/4 of the time in the list, so every roommate appears more or less the same amount.

If I run the code, Python tells me the Keyboardexecution is interrupted. and it doesn't print anything. Here's the code:

```
import random

a1 = input("Time ") #the amount of times the items should be selected

a2 = int(a1)#converting string to integer

def fair1(a2):#defining function, bc i wanna do more plans with the same function
    liste1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]#list of the roommates in the household
    while a2 >= 1:
        if a2 >= 1:#so it runs till the loop hits 0
            a2 = a2-1#so every loop gets smaller by 1
            random.choice(liste1)
            x1 = liste1.count("a")#counting for the elements
            x2 = liste1.count("b")
            x3 = liste1.count("c")
            x4 = liste1.count("d")
            while x1 >= a2/4:#if a appears more than 1/4 of total it should be removed, but come back when its not 1/4
                liste1 = ["b", "c", "d"]
            while x2 >= a2/4:
                liste1 = ["a", "c", "d"]
            while x3 >= a2/4:
                liste1 = ["a", " b", "d"]
            while x4 >= a2/4:
                liste1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
        return fair1(a2-1) #to give the information to the function
    print(liste1)
            
print(fair1(a2))#to create an ouput
```

I expected that the program would run perfectly. It should print one item per each turn in dependency to how often the item has already been chosen.

Comment: Do you know what `while` means in Python?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide an example of the error python gives you? (Possibly the entire Traceback)

Comment: Well, got it already solved guys. tysm for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    import random

a1 = input("Time ")  # the amount of times the items should be selected

a2 = int(a1)  # converting string to integer


def fair1(a2):  # defining function, bc i wanna do more plans with the same function
    choices = []
    liste1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]  # list of the roommates in the household
    a3 = a2
    while a2 >= 1:
        a2 = a2 - 1  # so every loop gets smaller by 1
        choices.append(random.choice(liste1)) # add the random selection to a list
        x1 = choices.count("a")  # counting for the elements
        x2 = choices.count("b")
        x3 = choices.count("c")
        x4 = choices.count("d")
        if x1 >= a3 / 4:  # if a appears more than 1/4 of total it should be removed, but come back when its not 1/4
            try: # we use a try except to avoid error if the value doesn't exist
                liste1.remove('a')
            except ValueError:
                pass
        if x2 >= a3 / 4:
            try:
                liste1.remove('b')
            except ValueError:
                pass
        if x3 >= a3 / 4:
            try:
                liste1.remove('c')
            except ValueError:
                pass
        if x4 >= a3 / 4:
            try:
                liste1.remove('d')
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return choices  # to give the information to the function


print(fair1(a2))  # to create an ouput
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).